# Take values under the range of the column with a specific name "Statu"

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make the change that part of this line: `If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Details").Range("V" & counter) = "KO" And _`.
That part where it states `Range("V" & counter)` , i need to make it take values under a specific column in the sheet which starts with "Statu"
Below is my code any ideas how can i proceed thanks.

```
  Function not_processed() As Double
    Dim counter As Double
    not_processed = 0
    counter = 2
    Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Details").UsedRange.Rows.count >= counter
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Details").Range("V" & counter) = "KO" And _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Details").Range("b" & counter) <> "" Then
            not_processed = not_processed + 1
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Should the "Statu" string be the column header, and the header should be situated on the first row?

Comment: `I need to make the change that part of this line:` So where are you stuck?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: I think he needs to use the column where "Situ" is the header, instead of "V"..

Comment: @FaneDuru: Yes. I want to understand where is he stuck with the code? What has he tried to find `Situ`...

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: Obviously nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Try the adapted function, please:

```
Function not_processed() As Double
    Dim counter As Long, sh As Worksheet, sitCell As Range
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Details")
    Set sitCell = sh.rows(1).Find(What:="Situ", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
    If sitCell Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No ""Situ"" column header could be found...": Exit Function
    
    not_processed = 0
    counter = 2
    Do While sh.UsedRange.rows.count >= counter
        If sh.cells(counter, sitCell.Column) = "KO" And _
                        sh.Range("b" & counter) <> "" Then
            not_processed = not_processed + 1
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

The code assumes that "Situ" can be found on the first row of the processed sheet...

Comment: Set sitCell = sh.rows(1).Find("Situ") for that part line of code it should be like Cells(1, i) to detect the specific name column where it is situated to take the values

Comment: Just one suggestion. Use complete parameters of `.Find`.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: Not bad, but searching for a string **in a row**, most of the optional parameters could be omitted, I think (After, SerarchOrder, SearchDirection, SearchFormat...). I do not imagine a reason to not return the cell with that specific string. It will be returned even if the string is part of a bigger one. I (only) suppose that "Situ" may be part of a bigger word (Situation, for instance...). I do not imagine a formula to be used like header, even not impossible, but in order to use that, he should state it, I think...

Comment: @GPO LIMITED: No any `i` or Cell is necessary. At that point `i` did not have a value, anyhow. The header is searched in the first row and VBA recognize the row as a range. In this way, no necessary to set a lot of method `Optional` parameters. Test it, please...

Comment: `It will be returned even if the string is part of a bigger one.` Well, `.Find` always remembers it's previous settings. I am more concerned about `LookAt:` and `MatchCase:`. If `LookAt:=xlWhole` then **Situ** in **Situation** will not be returned. Similarly for "Situ" and "Situ " (notice the blank space?). Also if `MatchCase:=True` then **Situ <> SITU**

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: You are right about `LookAt`. It only happened that I (almost) always use `XlPart`. Even if I do not know what he really needs, from this point of view. But it is more probable to be `XlPart`. I will add it, too. About `MatchCase` he must state something, I think. Otherwise, the code returns without caring about the word case.